# allocation failure for large arrays in c using malloc

Tags: c, xcode, heap-memory, large-data

I use 'malloc()' to allocate memory:

- **big** arrays (2,17GB, 380,9MB, 166,9MB, ...) to read in data;
- **smaller** arrays (69MB, ...) for calculations.

I first allocate big arrays for the data (and read in the data from file). Then I allocate the smaller memory.

During execution, while allocating a small **69MB** array, I get an 'allocation failure' error and my program crashes.

Can I make **adjustments** so I could allocate the 69MB array?

Some **remarks**:

- When I **reduce** the size from 69MB to **17MB**, everything works just fine.
- If I run my program multiple times at the **same** moment (with the 17MB array) no error occurs: There is enough memory in the RAM
- If I do **not** read in one of the big (166,9MB) data arrays, allocating the 69MB afterwards still gives an error: Even though I use less memory, allocation fails.

**Info**

- Mac OS X 10.6.8, 6-Core Intel Xeon (64bit), 16GB RAM
- Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: You'll have to give more information, ideally a small C program to reproduce the issue, if you want to get a sensible answer.

Comment: Can you post the code used to allocate your arrays? How did you arrive at the "17MB is safe" figure? Was it chosen arbitrarily or is this the maximum size you found you could allocate through experimentation?

Comment: Have you run something like `top` to check that, in fact, you really do have sufficient space in RAM and/or swap to malloc the amount of RAM that you are asking for? Bear in mind that your program isn't the only thing occupying space in RAM.

Comment: Reading the NOTES in the man page may give you some insight as to where to look. Without some code to look at, there isn't much further we can do.

Comment: How much do you know about what the other processes are doing? When you are allocating, are you ever freeing other arrays? Where I am going with this is: Just because you have enough ram doesn't mean you can allocate one giant raft if that ram space is fragmented. Malloc will fail if there isn't a contiguous chunk available that's big enough. Have you sonsidered using linked lists instead? Can you can live with the performance hit and the extra overhead of storing the pointers for at least some of your data?

Comment: Are you hitting a process limit?  On *nix you would check with ulimit.